# Bubble wrapped the brickles?

Tags: listening

What does the guy say in the blank [here](https://youtu.be/YdcmWkMkH5U?t=258)? It sounds like "brickles."

"I packed up all the files and bubble wrapped the []."

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me, given the list that follows.

Comment: Sounds like 'bread-rolls' or 'bed-rolls', but it could just be a nonsense word as @Robusto suggests.

Comment: How are we meant to know what was said when we didn't hear it?

Comment: @curiousdannii You can hear it in the video if you follow the OP's link (the word "here"). OP, sometimes it's hard to see the links on this site, so it's a good idea to make it really clear from context that there's a link.

Comment: It's awful enunciation (typical of this kind of cartoon), but it sounds like "bubble-wrap the breakables". That would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that it’s ***breakables***
(i.e., fragile items, which would need bubble wrap
as protection against shock/impact).

Comment: Great work.  I listened to the sentence three times and didn't figure this out.

Comment: Don't feel bad; I needed five times.